# Joining two SQL Queries. Get values of name using ID in second query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
employee:
    cid name
    1   john
    2   joe

manages
    mid employee_id manager_id
    1   1            2

result:
    employee manager
    john       joe
    joe        null
```

employee_id and manager_id are foreign keys.

I have tried

```
SELECT name, manager_id FROM employee 
LEFT JOIN manages ON employee.cid = manages.employee_id;
```

But the result is

```
employee manager
john       2
joe        null
```

How can I get the name of cid 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one more left join to the employee table:

```
select e1.name employee, e2.name manager
from employee e1
left join manages m on m.employee_id = e1.cid
left join employee e2 on m.manager_id = e2.cid
```